# Why do dart allow non-Future returning async?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

It's almost like so I can write an `async` that is intended ***not*** to be `awaitable` outside by designating it as, say, `void` not `Future<void>`

```dart
void fetchUserOrder() async {
  // Imagine that this function is fetching user info from another service or database.
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('Large Latte');
  print('After Large Latte');
}

void main() async {
  fetchUserOrder();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('Fetching user order...');
  print('After Fetching user order...');
}
```

Print:

```
Fetching user order...
After Fetching user order...
Large Latte
After Large Latte
```

This is **sooo** so ***unallowed*** in `.NET` and also `c++20` realm.

- I wonder why `dart` let `async` functions return non-`Future`?
- Wouldn't this end up with ***intended*** hidden `async` in API all over the places?

Comment: A quick comment: dart does not allow *any* non-Future, it explicitly allows `void` as the *only* non-`Future`.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm new here at dart. Thank you for clearifying. Also please post some answer if you know/suspect the reason behind that design decision.

Comment: Once you realise that it's just `void`, you'll also realise that `.NET` is in exactly the same boat of allowing `async void`. Dart isn't the sole example of this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah. That makes very sense! Task-scheduling shall ***not*** allowed to be waited outside.

Comment: If you want a lint (and therefore a warning) about missing `Future<void>` as return value in `async` marked methods, you can add the `avoid_void_async` to the analyzer. The lint is documented here: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_void_async.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't force you to await futures. Futures existed before `await` was introduced, so it couldn't really.
That means that you can always *not* await a future. There are lints to make it harder to avoid, but nothing prevents you from just defining `ignore(Object? _){}` and doing `ignore(futureOperation());`.

Since a `Future` is an object, you can assign `Future` to `Object` and to anything you can assign `Object` to, including `void`. That also means that an async function can be cast to a function type with a return type of `void`, like:

```dart
void Function() f = () async { .... };
```

You can call that and ignore the result.
And that too is why you can declare the return type of an `async` method to be `void` or `dynamic` or `Object?`. Because the type system has to allow it anyway.
It would have been different if `Future` was not a subtype of `Object`, but that would also make a lot of things more complicated.

It can be used deliberately. If you actually *do* want a function which does asynchronous operations in the background, but you don't want anyone to wait for them, you can do so:

```dart
void log(String message) async {
  (await getLogger()).log(message);
}
```

This function will (eventually) log the message, but you don't have to wait for it to do so.

You could write essentially the same function without using `async` too, so forcing disallowing a `void` return type with `async` would just be an unnecessary obstacle, forcing you to rewrite the same thing in a less readable way.

```dart
void log(String message) {
  getLogger().then((logger) {
    logger.log(message);
  });
}
```

(It's not *exactly* the same because the `async` version currently does return a future, it just tells you not to use it but typing it as `void`. You *can*, even if you *really shouldn't*, cast the `void` return to `dynamic` and `await` it anyway. The non-`async` version doesn't return a future at all.)

Comment: Could you please also write `log(String message)` in an equivalent version calling `Future<>` favour (without `async` designated)?

Comment: "cast the `void` return": **yikes!** ***Why on earth*** would they allow that!! Sooo weird! Thanks for direct-chaining version.